# Determine what white space in variable actually is

Tags: php, mysql, import-from-excel

I'm uploading data from an Excel sheet into a mySQL database using PHP, and I haven't found a perfect way to trim out non-pertinent information from what I'm uploading.

I've read several posts here on StackOverflow regarding white space detection and removal in PHP, and read through at the official guide on [PHP's Trim function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) regarding the various things that can cause white space other than a literal `space` character, such as `tab`, `new line`, `carriage return`, `NUL-byte`, or `vertical tab`.

Most of these can be removed using the `trim()` function, but I found a few other characters that are present in some of my uploaded cells, so i wrote this function that I pass each uploaded variable through:

```
function smartTrim($value) {

  if ($value == null) {
    return null;
  }

  $value = trim($value);
  $value = trim($value,chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0));

  return $value;

}
```

While this has worked so far, **I have a value that is being uploaded that *still* has some sort of white space in it that I'm not finding, and I don't know how to    determine what it is.**

In Excel, it looks like this:

```
 Q12345  /* [space]Q12345 */
```

After uploading, using PHP's `echo` outputs this:

```
 Q12345 /* [space]Q12345 */
```

In mySQL, it appears like this however:

```
Â Q12345 /*Â[space]Q12345 */
```

Is there some way in PHP that I can go through EACH character in a string and output what UTF character it is so I can figure out how to strip this weird `Â` symbol, along with any subsequent weird things that Excel might be putting into my cells?

Comment: `Â` means you've got a mangled string due to character set mismatch. e.g. unicode string in an iso8859 environment.

Comment: A non-breaking space should just be a non-breaking space (&nbsp; or &#160;). There are other Unicode space characters in the U+2002-U+200B and U+202F, U+205F and U+FEFF (the latter being the esoteric Zero-Width-Non-Breaking-Space). A CleanItUp sub function should be able to take care of these and other rogue characters.

Comment: Yeah I think part of my question was "What are ALL of the possible characters that I MIGHT have to trim at any given point?"  How do I convert `U+2002` into something like `chr(0xC2)`?

Comment: @MarcB - I think your comment is really helpful in having me understand what exactly is going on - instead of just how to fix it.  Can you explain how I ensure that there is no character set mismatch?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to check ALL whitespace to see if it's a certain character, but you could try it from a different angle:

```
function clean($string) {

   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $string); 
}
```

This just cuts out anything that's not in the regular expression above:

```
A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
```

This may or may not meet your needs, but if the only values you're going to want in this are A-Z and numbers, this will work.

Comment: Hmmm - this might actually be easier than what I was originally trying to do.  I don't `think` I'll ever see anything outside of this in a value I want to upload - but I'm also still interested in a solution to my actual question... just to learn.